# node js server safari client connection fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, safari, cors

I have a simple html-js<-ajax->nodejs server loop as a test base for my app 
core.

It works on windows 8 with browsers: IE11, Chrome45,firefox40,opera31.. and fails on safari 5.1.7

Here is the client code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<script language="javascript">
var url="http://127.0.0.1:1001";

function sendData(rawData) {

    var strout="";
    var data=encodeURIComponent(rawData);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
          if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            strout=decodeURIComponent(xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("opResult").innerHTML="srv-sent "+strout
            }
        }

    xhr.send(data);
    alert("sent = "+rawData)
}

//+++++++++++++++++++
function send(){
var v=document.getElementById("ta").value;
sendData(v);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="send" onclick="send()">
<br>
<textarea id="ta" cols=40 rows=10> </textarea>
<br>
<div id="opResult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the server code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
    var postData="",cmdQ=[],resout=[];

    if (request.method == 'POST') {
      request.on('data', function (data) {
         postData += data;
      });
    }
    console.log("SRV got data:"+postData);
    request.on('end', function () {
    console.log("got post: "+decodeURIComponent(postData));
    resout="SRVRep: got "+decodeURIComponent(postData);
    response.writeHead(200, {
             'Content-Type': 'text/html',
             'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
             }); 
        response.end(encodeURIComponent(resout), "utf-8");  
        console.log("sent "+resout);
        post_data="";
    });

}).listen(1001,'127.0.0.1');
console.log("server initialized to port 1001");
```

To make the web simulation complete, I am running (npm installed ) http-server (port 8080) and the client is a link in the index.html.

The simulation is simple; on the client type something in the text-box, click send, and you should get the

response showing in the opResult div. And it does, in everything except safari.

Debug code shows safari sends a blank message... CORS problem?!?

Safari experts please advise.

Comment: When you visit the site, is your URL bar pointing at `127.0.0.1:1001`?

Comment: it points at localhost:8080 (node http-server directory) ; index.html shows in the browser. Therein is a link to safaritest.html, test ap. which holds the html above. It ajax-connects to 127.0.0.1:1001 (exept in safari)

Comment: Safari is really, really, _really_ picky about cross origin requests.  I'm pretty sure it differentiates between 'localhost' and 127.0.0.1, so that would be a CORS offense. Further, you're ajax-ing a different port; there's another CORS offense.  If you open your error console (Develop->Show Error Console) and post any related errors down here or as an edit to your question, that would really help.

Comment: Error Console is empty, though I think I might have seen it before (||red herring?). That's why I guessed its a CORS problem, in which case there might be a header solution?!? Either way I can't run the simplest node based web app on safari, and I can't believe that's ok in either node or safari community. To do so I need a static file server (http-server :8080) serving up the app, and an app file/data storage server :1001. If safari sees localhost!=127.0.0.1 and can't handle IO to different ports, then its toast, and I can't see that.. I must be missing something!

Comment: My bad of impatience. I ran the test again and this time I waited in case the error showed after timeout; and our suspicions are spot on, 2 errors: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:1001. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Now that know the problem(s)...?!?

Comment: Excellent work.  I shall write an answer...

Answer (score 1):

(summary at bottom)

#### Problem

> I need a static file server (http-server :8080) serving up the app,
>   and an app file/data storage server :1001.

This is your current model: The client accesses static data and the app/data as two different [origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) (wiki):

```
(current model: client receives content from two origins)

http-server:8080 ─┐            ┌─> node:1001
                  └─> client <─┘
```

#### option #1: Reverse Proxy

A much more popular design is the "reverse-proxy" ([nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/), [apache](http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/116-simple-apache-reverse-proxy-example)), in which the http-server serves static data *and* acts as an interface to your node app. This way, your both content types come from the same origin and port, but still see performance gains:

```
(reverse-proxy model: everything comes from localhost:8080)

node:1001 <─────> apache or nginx:8080 <──┐
                                          └─> client
```

...but you're not **using nginx or apache**.  No worries.  There's an NPM package to do just this with the stack you're already using [here](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). See my [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XtKWxBud) for an example.

This model has the added advantage of providing all the configurability of your http-server to your node app, giving you advanced security and optimization options such as request caching.

> ...localhost!=127.0.0.1 and can't handle IO to different ports...

This is officially a CORS violation, but it wasn't always this way. Check out [MDN's same origin policy documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). This fairly recent policy necessarily mitigates problematic cross-site scripting attacks.

#### option #2: Cross Origin Sharing Standard ([w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/))

That being said, there **is** an officially sanctioned way to make ajax requests across origins, but the "other" domain must know and accept your traffic. There's two ways of achieving this:

- Simple GET and POST requests can be allowed by adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to your responses in your node application.
- POST requests with a content-type other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain` need a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

#### Summary:

You can avoid violating the browser's same-origin policy either of two ways:

1. By implementing a reverse-proxy, so both your static and dynamic content come from the same place (in your case, localhost:8080)
2. By adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to your responses in node, or in rare cases, preflighting the request.

Comment: many thanks James.. I was already on the trail of option 2 (ok on server header, looking for right client header). So I added xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/plain") right after xhr.open; can't believe it was that easy. Retested on all browsers and all-a-ok.